# Waiting for available sockets - PHP 7.2 , Apache 2.4, MySQL 5.7

Tags: php, apache, zend-framework

We are developing a web application using PHP 7.2 (Zend Framework), Apache 2.4 & MySQL 5.7. Randomly the application is taking ages to load a web page and at the bottom left corner **"waiting for available sockets"** message is being displayed. If we close that tab and open the same link in new tab, webpage is loading pretty fast.

Is this related to any max connection limit in PHP 7.2? As we never faced this issue in PHP 5.6

Is there any workaround to fix this problem?

Comment: you might want to checkout this page https://unfortunatelystopped.com/fix-waiting-available-socket-error.html/

Comment: Thank you @virtualone

But I am worried that end user will not perform these many steps to fix this issue and we might loose our end users.

Is there anything which can be handled at server end?